# Will the Games.Snapshots.open and all other deprecated Games API calls continue to work after Google Drive Android API shut down on December 6, 2019?

Tags: deprecated, google-play-games, google-drive-android-api, google-play-developer-api

Last year I have received an e-mail about the Google Drive Android API deprecation and that it will be shut down on December 6, 2019. However, in fact, I am not using the Google Drive Android API directly, only by the means of the Saved Games feature of the Google Play Games Services.

Further, GoogleApiClient and it's related API calls got deprecated since the version 11.6.0.

However, accessing Saved Games and other features of the Google Play Games Services through these deprecated calls are still functioning without any problem.

My questions are:
- Will these deprecated Games Services API calls, the GoogleApiClient and especially the Saved Games data retrievals from Google Drive continue to work after the Google Drive Android API got shut down on December 6, 2019?
- Is there already a date planned when these deprecated Games Service API calls will cease to function and will be shut down?

I only know about the planned shut down of the Google Drive Android API, and I assume, that all the calls to Google Drive will be, or are already updated behind the Google Play Game Services. However, I am not sure if they will be updated behind its deprecated versions as well.

At this moment I have no warnings at the Google Play Developer console regarding deprecated API usage.

Please, can someone confirm that the deprecated calls, like Games.Snapshots.open, will still function after December 6, 2019?

A sample code showing the retrieval of a saved game from the Google Drive, which is deprecated, but is still working:

```
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult> task =
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult>() {
        @Override
        protected Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result = null;

            try {
                result = Games.Snapshots.open(googleApiClient, SNAPSHOT_NAME, false).await();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // Error handling
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Snapshots.OpenSnapshotResult result) {
            snapshotResult = result;

            if(result != null) {
                cloudProcessResultForLoad();
            } else {
                // Error handling
            }
        }
    };

task.execute();
```

Comment: This is a Customer Service question that should be directed to Google via their site. We can't speak on behalf of Google in regards to their plans for their services. Questions about code related to using the services are on-topic here, but questions about the services and what features will or won't work in the future are not.

Comment: With that said, the entire purpose of notifying you that the features are deprecated is to let you know that they may stop working in the near future, and allow you time to update to new functionality before that happens. So you should be working now on replacing that functionality instead of concerning yourself with whether or not it will keep working, because the fact that it's being deprecated at all means it's going away at some point.

Comment: Stopped working today.